# Derive/ prove: p(a,b|c) = p(a|b,c).p(b|c)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

How can this expression be derived?

`p(a,b|c) = p(a|b,c).p(b|c)`

where `a,b,c` are random variables.

UPDATE: from the following video lecture: `Graphical Models 2- Christopher Bishop`. ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0AWH5UFyOk ) skip to 3 min 11sec

Comment: Not a proof, more of a way to rapidly chech such equations mentally:  conditional probability is probability! Note that in your equation, $c$ only occurs as conditioner, and in all the $P(\cdot | \cdot)$ factors. So just drop $c$! Then we have $P(a,b) = P(a|b) P(b)$ which you certailny recognice as true, so your formula is true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the following facts:

(1)$P(A\cap B|C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$

(2)$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A|B\cap C)P(B\cap C)$

Comment: Thanks! The second rule helped.

Comment: No problem. Also just tip when asking questions here, more people usually more likely to answer if you showed what you have tried regardless whether its right or not. This also just helps in general to make sure we can provide information that you having the most trouble on

Comment: I could not figure out the second expansion and was stuck. I'll add what I've tried next time..

Comment: No its fine, just a little tip